# Sair de dois Foreachs PHP

Tags: php, foreach

Preciso iterar varias collections e caso encontre uma condição devo sair de mais de um laço de iteração.

Ex.:

```
    foreach ($order->getItemCollection() as $item) {
        foreach ($order->getFreight()->getPackageCollection() as $packs) {
            foreach ($packs->getItemCollection() as $packItem) {
                if ($item->getSku() == $packItem->getSku()) {
                    ...
                    break ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Como posso fazer isso ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Você também pode usar `break 2` para sair dos dois `loop´s`:

**[Exemplo: Ideone](https://ideone.com/vqo3d0)**

```
foreach ($order->getItemCollection() as $item) {
     foreach ($order->getFreight()->getPackageCollection() as $packs) {
         foreach ($packs->getItemCollection() as $packItem) {
             if ($item->getSku() == $packItem->getSku()) {
                 ...
                 break 2 ;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

O argumento numérico (2) serve para indicar quantas estruturas aninhadas o `break` deve interromper, [veja mais aqui.](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.break.php)

Answer (score 3):

Pode usar uma variável;

```
$sair = FALSE;
foreach ($order->getItemCollection() as $item) {
    foreach ($order->getFreight()->getPackageCollection() as $packs) {
        foreach ($packs->getItemCollection() as $packItem) {
            if ($item->getSku() == $packItem->getSku()) {
                ...
                $sair = true;
            }
            if ($sair) break;
        }
        if ($sair) break;
    }
    if ($sair) break;
}
```